# create a branch from new folder (non-versioned code)

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have just created a new folder/project and a lot of new code, I want to commit this code to a new branch, how can I do this using torotiseSVN?

This newly created code is never checkedout/committed, its pure unversioned code

Comment: How it related to trunk of existing repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create (in repobrowser) branch from trunk at server-side
2. Checkout branch into new, unrelated to trunk, WC
3. Sync content of WC with files from "a new folder/project"

**PS**: Fix workflow and in future always start from preparing working space (new branch), you save a lot of time and avoid monkey-job from p.3